# How to set up an Array with T[]?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am having a problem when trying to create an array to sort. It has told me when trying to compile my main method. I am still learning java and not sure if I have to extend T somehow to make this work. My question is, how do I set up an array for the require T[]?

```
int[] numArray = {99, 2, 1, 88, 66, 32};
    Sorter.insertSort(numArray, numArray.length);

SorterMain.java:24: error: method insertSort in class Sorter cannot be applied to given types;
    Sorter.insertSort(numArray);
          ^
  required: T[],int
  found: int[]
```

When I try to make it with T it says it cannot find it.

My sorter class is as follows.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void insertSort(T[] theArray, int n)
   {
      int count1 = 0;
      for(int unsorted = 1; unsorted < n; ++unsorted)
      {
         T nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
         int loc = unsorted;
         while((loc > 0) && (theArray[loc-1].compareTo(nextItem) > 0))
         {
            theArray[loc] = theArray[loc-1];
            loc--;

         } //end while

         theArray[loc] = nextItem;
         count1++;

      }//end for

      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {

      System.out.print(theArray[i] + " ");

      }//end for

      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.println("Number of times moved: " + count1);


   }//end insertSort
```

Comment: Pretty irrelevant side note: If you want to follow the official MoS for Java, your brackets should be on the same line as the bit they're associated with (function definition, `while` loop, etc.) and there should be a space between keywords like `for` and `while` and the parens after them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `insertSort` requires you to pass the array’s length for some reason, so:

```
Sorter.insertSort(numArray, numArray.length);
```

The function itself should really be the one doing that, though.

The other problem is that `int`s are primitives, and generics don’t work with those in Java; you need to use an `Integer[]`.

Comment: Unfortunately this still gives me the error mentioned above required: T[],int
  found: int[],int

Comment: @Robert: Sorry, see update: declare it as `Integer[] numArray = …`.